# JAX-WS Client throws SOAPFaultException instead of custom exception

Tags: java, jax-ws

I have a JAX-WS based application that I am developing. I generate WSDL from the server using `wsgen` and then build the client library using `wsimport`. I am writing my own custom exceptions to throw with my method calls. The code is structured as follows.

Custom Exception Class:

```
@WebFault(faultBean = "com.mysite.FaultBean")
public class MyCustomException extends Exception {
  private FaultBean faultInfo;

  //Getters/Setters/Constructors...
}
```

Custom Fault Bean:

```
public class FaultBean {
  private String message;
  private List<String> messages;

  //Getters/Setters/Constructors...
}
```

I then throw `MyCustomException` from my methods in my web service endpoint. When I call one of my web service methods and it throws an exception the client is getting a `SOAPFaultException` instead of `MyCustomException`. Why is the custom exception not getting used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a bit of investigation it turns out the exceptions that were being thrown as a `SOAPFaultException` were not coming from where I thought they were. They actually were not thrown as `MyCustomException`. So, to solve this for all cases I took advantage of Spring AOP and created an Around aspect to wrap all of my calls to the web service implementation layer.

In this aspect I catch any exception thrown and wrap it in a `MyCustomException` before rethrowing it. My client can then handle the exception properly.